# Calendar events created by Eventbrite disappear after 1 second

Tags: ios, calendar

The Eventbrite app allows you to "Add to Calendar" on any event. I made sure that it has permissions to access my calendar under privacy settings. However, after adding an event to the calendar, it disappears after 1 second.

I think this may be related to my deleting of the Eventbrite calendar in the past. I was hoping it would try to recreate it, but alas it doesn't. Any suggestion for how to get this feature to work again? I tried searching, but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR, manually create a calendar named `Eventbrite`, then try again.

---

It appears the logic they are using is the follows:

1. If there is no calendar named `Eventbrite`, create a new calendar named `Eventbrite` under the same account as your default Calendar account.

   Note that if your default Calendar account is an iCloud account, this will work just fine. However if your default Calendar is under an account that doesn't allow creating calendars via the Calendar interface (e.g. a Gmail account), this will likely fail. Therefore you must manually create the Calendar so that the algorithm can skip this step (e.g. on calendar.google.com).
2. Create the new event in the `Eventbrite` calendar.

---

How I found this out:

- By recording the screen, I could quickly click into the event that was temporarily created and notice that it gets added to an "Eventbrite" calendar. The Eventbrite calendar doesn't exist on my phone though.
- By installing the app on a new iOS device, I do indeed notice it creates an Eventbrite calendar.
- When I try creating a new calendar under a Gmail account using the Calendar App interface, it doesn't actually create the calendar.